# Plugin/ActiveX to intercept PDFs in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, add-on, pdf-reader

I have a web application that generates PDF documents that can only be read once before being destroyed server side.
Whenever you ask for a PDF, it is automatically displayed in a new Internet Explorer window.
I don't have any way to modify this application.

Thus, PDFs cannot be read again after being generated. My problem is that I need to do an additional thing with them.

The only choice I see is to develop some program that'd act in place of Adobe Reader to get the PDF content, so I can save it or do whatever I want with it, then send this content to Adobe Reader for display in Internet Explorer.

I'm not sure where to start, am I looking at making an ActiveX control that'd call an external program (mine), which would itself call the Adobe Reader program?
How do I make this ActiveX control react to PDFs the same way Adobe Reader does?

Comment: I think you need a PDF SDK that can be display PDFs? May be Foxit PDF SDK ActiveX can help you? i can be integrated to IE and display PDF. You only need to set the path or buffer of the PDF file.

Comment: @Amy No, I need a control to do something with the pdf BEFORE displaying it (which is done by Adobe Reader)